# How to get the user name using a Microsoft user id?

Tags: azure, windows-store-apps, winjs, azure-mobile-services

Am working on a windows store javascript application. I have used the microsoft login authentication from azure as follows.

```
client.login("microsoftaccount").done(function (results) {;
userId = results.userId;
refreshTodoItems();
var message = "You are now logged in as: " + userId;

var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message);
dialog.showAsync().done(complete);
}
```

Am able to retreive the userid such as "Microsoftaccount:c2892313bla...."

How am I supposed to retreive the associated UserName for that Microsoft account ID?

Answer (score 0):

When you're logged on, on any scripts on the server side you can query for the *identities* of the user (via the `user.getIdentities()` function), which will give you an object with access tokens which you can use to talk to the authentication providers. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx has an example on how to get the user name for MS account (and other providers as well).

Comment: Hey Carlosfigueira!. Am still confused in the implementation part.  Would be great if you can send a worked out sample project to retreive the username.
E-mail:amarzeno@outlook.com